# Which parcel is causing TransactionTooLargeException?

Tags: android

I targeted my Android app for Nougat, and I started getting TransactionTooLarge exceptions during (I believe) onSaveInstance state of fragments. I say "I believe" because I'm not exactly for sure where it's happening. Here's a sample stack trace during a crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 835604 bytes
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3806)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6120)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 835604 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3621)
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3798)
... 7 more
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 835604 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3621)
at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3798)
```

The problem: nothing in this stack trace contains tells me what parcel is causing the exception, nor what line in my code is causing it. In researching the exception it's clear I have to cut down the size of parcels that are too large, but my attempts at guessing the offending parcels have not solved the problem. Is there any way through Android Studio to determine exactly which parcel is causing the problems?

Comment: when I had this problem, I added debug code to my onSave to store my data into a Parcel and the checked it's size and logged this for analysis